# Jasmine unit test that triggers mouse events in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular-2+, jasmine

I have the following jasmine test spec which triggers the mouse events in my directive. As you can see there is a lot of code duplication here, I am repeating the events here.

```
describe('Test for my module', () => {
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
        let de: DebugElement[];
        let service: MyService = new MyService();

        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [Move, TestComponent],
                providers: [MyService]
            });
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
            service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
            fixture.detectChanges();
            de = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(Move));
        });

// My test spec. This is where I need advice for removing the code duplication.
it('test the move event', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
                let object = spyOn(service.x, 'emit');
                spyObj.and.callThrough();
                de[0].triggerEventHandler('mousedown', { pageX: 10, pageY: 10 });
                de[0].triggerEventHandler('mousemove', { pageX: 40, pageY: 20 });
                expect(service.x.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ x: 30, y: 10 });
                object.calls.reset();
                de[0].triggerEventHandler('mousemove', { pageX: 45, pageY: 25 });
                expect(service.x.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ x: 35, y: 15 });
                object.calls.reset();
                de[0].triggerEventHandler('mousemove', { pageX: 50, pageY: 30 });
                expect(service.x.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ x: 40, y: 20 });

            }));
```

Could anyone help me by suggesting any way to avoid this duplication?

Comment: I was wondering if I can use an inline function here to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did come up with one alternative which is as follows:

```
    function triggerEvents(debugElement: DebugElement, eventName: string, object: any){
            debugElement.triggerEventHandler(eventName, object);
        }

    function expectAndReset(spy: Function, object: any, spyObj: jasmine.Spy) {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(object);
        spyObj.calls.reset();
    }

    it('test the move event', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
        let spyObj = spyOn(service.x, 'emit');
        spyObj.and.callThrough();
        triggerEvents(de[0],'mousedown', { pageX: 10, pageY: 10 });
        triggerEvents(de[0],'mousemove', { pageX: 40, pageY: 20 });
        expectAndReset(service.x.emit,{ x: 30, y: 10 },spyObj);
        triggerEvents(de[0],'mousemove', { pageX: 45, pageY: 25 });
        expectAndReset(service.x.emit,{ x: 35, y: 15 },spyObj);
        triggerEvents(de[0],'mousemove', { pageX: 50, pageY: 30 });
        expectAndReset(service.x.emit,{ x: 40, y: 20 },spyObj);

    }));
```

I am not really satisfied with my own solution though, because the function implementation of triggerEvents is almost identical as the triggerEventHandler in the Angular Documentation. I am not doing anything special there. But I am hoping that the code reviewers on the community would comment or share their views and give me a better solution :)

Second Attempt:

```
        function triggerEvents(debugElement: DebugElement, eventName: string, object: any) {
            debugElement.triggerEventHandler(eventName, object);
        }

        function expectAndReset(spy: Function, object: any, spyObj: jasmine.Spy) {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(object);
            spyObj.calls.reset();
        }

        it('test the move event', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
            let spyObj = spyOn(service.x, 'emit');
            spyObj.and.callThrough();
            triggerEvents(de[0], 'mousedown', { pageX: 10, pageY: 10 });
            for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 5) {
                triggerEvents(de[0], 'mousemove', { pageX: 40 + i, pageY: 20 + i });
                expectAndReset(service.x.emit, { x: 30 + i, y: 10 + i }, spyObj);
            }

        }));
```

Somewhat satisfied with my second iteration.

Thank you.

Comment: You are fantastic!!!